# Replace globally HTML string in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a HTML string like this:

`<div>My cat</div><div>My dog</div><div>12345</div>`

I want to use Regex to replace globally string (change `</div><div>` into `<br/>`, then **remove all HTML, just keep `<br/>` only**:

`My cat<br/>My dog<br/>12345`

I tried with this code:

```
var formatHTMLQuill = function (stringHTML) {
  let t = stringHTML.replace('</div><div>', '<br/>');
  let n = t.replace(/<(?!br\s*\/?)[^>]+>/g, '')
  return n
}
```

But it's not work, result is `My cat<br/>My dog</div><div>12345`

Comment: I think it is replacing only the first occurrence in `let t = stringHTML.replace('</div><div>', '<br/>');`

Comment: @NambiMurugan Yeah, you need regexp with `g` flag to force `.replace` to do it multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify the below code:

```js
var formatHTMLQuill = function (stringHTML) {
let t = stringHTML.replace(/(<\/div><div>)/g, '<br/>');
let n = t.replace(/(<\/div>|<div>)/g, '');
return (n);
}

console.log(formatHTMLQuill('<div>My cat</div><div>My dog</div><div>12345</div>'));
```

Comment: Welcome @feedGit

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `<div>`  first and replace `</div>` with `<br/>`

```js
var formatHTMLQuill = function (stringHTML) {
  let t = stringHTML.replace(/\<div>/g, '');  
  
  let n = t.replace(/\<\/div>/g, '<br/>')
  return n
}

console.log(formatHTMLQuill("<div>test</div> <div>test1</div>"))
```

Comment: Anyway to remove <br/> at the end?

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegEx with the global flag `g`. The `g` modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).

```js
var html = `<div>My cat</div><div>My dog</div><div>12345</div>`

var formatHTMLQuill = function (stringHTML) {
  let t = stringHTML.replace(/<div>/ig,'')         //remove the start div
                    .replace(/<\/div>/ig, '<br/>') //replace the closing </div>
                    .replace(/(<br\/>\s*)+$/,'');  //remove the last <br/>
  return t;
}

console.log(formatHTMLQuill(html));
```

Comment: Anyway to remove <br/> at the end?